# What does the %||% expression do in R

Tags: r

I am working with some Code containing the expression `%||%`.

This is the context i encountered it:

```r
# Example list for minimal example 
df <- list(a=1,2,c=3)
# code
ind <- names(df) %||% seq_along(df)
```

But R cannot find the operator `%||%`. I guess a package is not installed but i do not know which one. I also cannot find it on google or stackoverflow.

**Could someone explain what it does and which package it belongs to?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's from `ggplot2` utilities.

```
"%||%" <- function(a, b) {
  if (!is.null(a)) a else b
}
```

You can find in [utilities.r](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/main/R/utilities.r#L1:L9)

Comment: It is not unique to `ggplot2`, rather many packages define it for convenience. Example of usage in base R > https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/96a9aa673e197229dcc56186fd5dd03b97609def/src/library/stats/R/add.R

Comment: Yup, it's the [null coalescing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_coalescing_operator), unfortunately R doesn't supply a native one but as seen it can be implemented in a single line of code and people do that again and again.